# Where in clause using linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

trying to convert a query which has 2 levels of where in clauses to linq and getting some errors. Can anybody help me on this?

Original Query:

```
select id 
from student 
where suId 
in (select suId 
    from subjects
    where cid 
    in (select id 
        from chapters 
        where chapter='C203'))
```

LINQ query:

```
 var query = (from s in dc.students
        let subs = (from su in dc.subjects
                        where su.cid == Convert.ToInt32(from c in dc.Chapters
                                                            where c.chapter == 'Ç203'
                                                            select c.id) //Single chapter id will be returned
                        select su.suid)
        where subs.Contains(s.sid)
        select s.id).ToArray();
```

Am getting below 2 errors while compiling app

1. 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains(System.Linq.ParallelQuery, TSource)' has some invalid arguments
2. Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Linq` is lazy-loading everything you don't need to cram everything into a single statement; you can do something like this:

```
var chapterIds = dc.Chapters
    .Where(c => c.Chapter == "C023")
    .Select(c => c.Id);
var subjectIds = dc.Subjects
    .Where(s => chapterIds.Contains(s.Cid))
    .Select(s => s.Suid);
var students = dc.Students
    .Where(s => subjectIds.Contains(s.Suid))
    .Select(s => s.Sid)
    .ToArray();
```

This way you can debug each subquery by looking at what it returns.

However, looking at your original select you can rewrite the whole thing as a `Join` and get rid of the bugging issue:

```
var students = dc.Chapters.Where(c => c.Chapter == "C023")
    .Join(dc.Subjects,
        c => c.Id,
        s => s.Cid,
        (chapter, subject) => subject)
    .Join(dc.Students,
        subj => subj.Suid,
        student => student.Suid,
        (subj, st) => st.Sid)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: seems join is much simpler solution. Thanks